# String and date

Tags: r

Convert a string S in the function parameter to a valid date format “yyy-mm-dd” and assign it to ans in R language
Code:

```
ans<-as.Date(S,format=“%Y-%m-%d)
```

I am getting output as NA. Please help to solve the error

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example ...

Comment: In other words what is `S`?

Answer (score 1):

It usually means that the string does not match your format pattern:

```r
as.Date("fd",format="%Y-%m-%d")
#> [1] NA
as.Date("2021-12-02",format="%Y-%m-%d")
#> [1] "2021-12-02"
as.Date("2021/12/02",format="%Y-%m-%d")
#> [1] NA
as.Date("2021",format="%Y-%m-%d")
#> [1] NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>